# Element not Floating Left

Tags: html, css

This is bothering the crap out of me and I can't see what's not allowing it to float left.

I've set a margin-left of 120px to the header text (450 Set, 230 Set, etc.) and did a float left to the link element with the image inside of it.

Here's the link to the site where it's happening: http://cl.ly/6lQa

What am I over looking or not seeing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the result to be?

Comment: Just for the image to float left of the rest of the text there. Right now it'd just be the header since I've only added the margin-left to that for now. But I couldn't even get that to work.

Comment: If you try validating the page you will find that the validator complains about some non-utf8 characters: http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the h2 tag that's screwing it up. Use a div tag instead and apply the styles that you want.

Generally, I refrain from using the h1,h2,h3,h4..... tags because they come with pre-done stylings. I prefer to create classes for all of my stylings and use div or span tags. Only if I'm doing SEO, I'll use some h1,h2 tags at the top, but nothing more than that.

On a side note, you should also try to get away from relying on float. It is not a good way to go..... different browsers handle it differently, and many times I get errors like what you were getting here. Instead of float, use position:relative and place the elements on the page by specifying the pixels at which you would like them (e.g. left:200px, top:100px etc).

I just started using [BlueprintCss](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), which provides a great framework to easily layout pages. It divides the page up in a grid, and using pre-defined classes, you layout the page (without floats!). It's amazing, you should look into it.

Comment: Use heading tags as it is proper HTML semantics to use them. If your concern is default styling, I would use a CSS reset.

Comment: Do you want Google to search your website? Crawlers use headings to determine what information is important to your site. I would strongly recommend against ignoring these tags simply because they are prestyled. It's common practice to remove the styling at the beginning of the CSS document if the prestyling bothers you.

Answer (score 1):

You should move `<h2 class="entry-title">` above the `a` element containing your image.

Comment: Did that and it does the same thing but it just puts the h2 above the image and still doesn't float.

Comment: @Marc: Is this the right look? http://i.stack.imgur.com/bfvkv.png - I did this using Firebug, and I'll write it up as an answer if it's correct.

Comment: Yes I accepted the other one too cause you both gave me the same answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Marc: No problem. For what it's worth, the reason changing `h2` to `div` works is because on approximately line 37 of `style.css`, you have CSS like this: `h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { clear: both; }` - that `clear: both` on `h2` was (I think) causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set a width on the `<h2>` that will fit into the remaining space (with the 120px margin) OR better yet use a `<div>` instead of the h2 and style the font the same way

Comment: Thanks! this worked. Any reason why the other way wouldn't work?

Comment: Adding style="width:120px" to the h2 in Firebug did not change anything for me in Firefox 4.

Comment: -1 for suggesting semantical change (using div instead of h2)

Comment: @Marc h tags take up the full width of their parents, so it is too wide to fit with the floated image, so it gets pushed below the image.

Comment: @August did you downvote the selected answer also (no), I wish I could -1 your comment for thinking it is not helpful to provide an answer

Comment: The point is that the markup should make sense even without CSS. If a piece of text is a heading semantically you should use one of the h tags and not a div.

Comment: @August well lets jump into the content, here it is entry titles, so semantically `<div class='entry-title'>` is infinitely more clear than `<h2`>

Comment: @Sydenam Well, an HTML parser knows nothing about your class attributes (or the meaning of them). If the page is viewed without CSS the titles will look like paragraph text.